# ProgressBar in Fragment Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I can't access the progress bar that I created in onCreateView of fragment in the Asynctask of fragment. Its caused by error is progressbar in onPreExecute is giving NullPointerException.
I created progressBar before I call asynctask. So what might be the problem?

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        new getAnnouncements().execute();

        return view;
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    private class getAnnouncements extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }
}
```

home_fragment.xml

```
 <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Once check in your home_fragment.xml layout the progress bar with id "progressbar" exists or not??

Comment: Silly me, it's id progressBar not progressbar. Thanks Chandrakanth.

Answer (score 2):

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```